# Creating more comprehensive associations with Querybuilder in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a query that would be for creating a list of Posts that have a Project that is associated to the user, and within that structure hit the right criteria for "tierAccess."

My query builder:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

        foreach($subs as $sub)
        {
            if($sub->getDisabled() == true)
            {
                continue;
            }

            $qb->select('p')
               ->from('App\Entity\ProjectPost', 'p')
               ->where('project = '.$sub->getProject()->getId())
               ->andwhere('p.Published = true')
               ->andwhere('p.TierAccess = '.$sub->getProjectTier()->getId())
               ->orderBy('p.PostTime', 'DESC');


            $query = $qb->getQuery();

           $object[] = $query->execute();
        }
```

What I am aiming to do is add posts that the user subscription will allow for, and within that subscription making sure their access to this post is allowed (ie: tierAccess).

I then return the object variable to pass along to my Twig template file.

The error I'm receiving is:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 45 near 'project = 3 AND': Error: 'project' is not defined.

My ProjectPost entity:

```
class ProjectPost
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $PostTitle;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $PostHero;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $PostType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $PostBody;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Project::class, inversedBy="projectPosts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $Project;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $TierAccess = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetimetz", nullable=true)
     */
    private $PostTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="projectPosts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $PostBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $PostCategories = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $Published;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $PostCover;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
    */
    private $PostSupporter = 0;
}
```

Comment: I did, Im reviewing because it's returning empty. Debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic mistake is this one:

```
->where('p.Project = '.$sub->getProject()->getId())
```

Notice that you declare `p` to be the alias of `Post`, and then you don't use it. And even if you define the property as `Project`, you were trying to use it as `project`.

---

Nevertheless, the whole thing is rather suspect. Executing a query within a loop usually points to something wrong with the design.

A simpler approach, using `WHERE IN` instead of a loop and multiple selects:

```
// get the "subs" ids in an array:
$subsIds = array_map(fn($s) => $s->getProject()->getId(), $subs); 

qb->select('p')
   ->from('App\Entity\ProjectPost', 'p')
   ->where('p.Project IN :subsIds')
   ->andwhere('p.Published = true')
   ->andwhere('p.TierAccess = '.$sub->getProjectTier()->getId())
   ->orderBy('p.PostTime', 'DESC')
   ->setParameter('subsIds', $subsIds)
;

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult;
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is TierAccess line, I updated the query as such: `$qb->andwhere('p.TierAccess IN (:tiers) OR p.TierAccess = ')` but the problem is I need an or statement saying whether tier access has these numbers, or if it's empty.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question, it's a different issue. In any case, it should probably be `p.TierAccess IS NULL`